# mysql_connect() error in php connection class

Tags: php, mysql

Am getting the following error when trying to access my log in page:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\members\connection.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Error while reading greeting packet. PID=3688 in C:\wamp\www\members\connection.php on line 7

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\members\connection.php on line 7

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\members\connection.php on line 7
```

The code for the connection class looks like this:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost:8081";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "hospital";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

Can any one help please?

The url am using to access the page is: 
localhost:8081/members

Mind you: other web folders are accessible from the root folder using the prefixed localhost and port number, its only this folder 'members' that has this error.

Comment: Wait, you're using 8081 for the database _and_ the web server?

Comment: Are those "other web folders" connecting to the MySQL server in the same way, using `localhost:8081` as a host name for the MySQL server?

Comment: On a side note, if you're just starting with PHP/MySQL programming, why not start right now using [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated and will be removed in the future](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) - see the red box.

Comment: hey Joachim, yes other web folders are accessing MYSQL server from the same port, I don't know why this particular file has issues.

Comment: Havelock I understand your concern, and currently learning how to use PDOs and have already used mysqli before but am supporting a legacy system here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change
`$mysql_hostname = "localhost:8081";`

to `$mysql_hostname = "localhost";` mysql use `3306` as default port.

or `$mysql_hostname = "localhost:3306";` or other **port** where you mysql is listning

Comment: Dear Ravi, I don't quite understand why I have to change the port since other applications are using the same configuration and running okay. It's only this one

Comment: but you can not use same ports for apache and myslq? only one process or program can use port at one time. you can check what port your mysql is using. please check in mysql configuration file.

Comment: Ravi this helped, thanks. I'll try to figure out why this particular file can't use this connection setting while other multiple files connect to the DB with the port 8081. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

Check the value of `max_allowed_packet` in your my.cnf MySQL config file.

or in php file

```
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 300);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, please see the edit. I've specified the port am using, since its not the default 3306. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change localhost:8080 to localhost:3306.

Comment: Hi Sonia, as I've indicated, another web folder is accessible through the port 8081. It's only this particular one that's posing problems

Answer (score 0):

Every once in a while I need to process a HUGE file. Though PHP probably isn't the most efficient way of processing the file, I'll usually use PHP because it makes coding the processing script much faster. To prevent the script from timing out, I need to increase the execution time of the specific processing script. Here's how I do it.

1.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Place this at the top of your PHP script and let your script loose!

2.
Set

```
max_execution_time=300
```

in php.ini file

Comment: Thanks YamaCasis, but am only accessing the login page, not processing anything, and getting the error